# How can i find in which file annotation name space is registered

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, annotations

In my symfony project the past coder has annotation like this

`/MyBundle/constraint/Annotation/Check.php`

```
namespace Der\CpsBundle\Constraint\Annotation;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

class Check extends Constraint{
```

Now the symfony documentation says

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-common/en/latest/reference/annotations.html

If you want to define your own annotations you just have to group them in a namespace and **register this namespace in the AnnotationRegistry**. Annotation classes have to contain a class-level docblock with the text @Annotation:

How in which file does that name space is registered. i want to know

Answer (score 0):

If you use Symfony2, then all your annotations automatically register (at least all constraint annotations). You just need to add comment for class like this:

```
/** @Annotation */
class MyAnnotation extends Constraint {...}
```

And of course when you use your annotation you need to import it

```
use My\Namespace\Constraint\Annotation as Annotation
....
/** @Annotation\MyAnnotation() */
class Form { ... }
```